# Node JS Not working On Centos Server

Tags: node.js, centos7, whm

I have a website hosting on centos 7 server. Latest Version of node js installed few months ago. Everything working normally until now.

When i hit any npm or node commands it immediately throw " Aborted " message with no errors.

I tried everything to resolve this issue including re-install and remove but not get any luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do following commands  `npm -v` `node -v` `which node` , whats the output?

Comment: What method did you follow to get node installed? Have you tried installing node via `nvm`? (`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash`)

Comment: Try installing without the global flag. Global may require sudo depending on your node installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your source was corrupted for npm and npx to interoperate normally. Never run these commands for NodeJS using root. I wrote a bash shell script to insure npm is sourced, installed, and configured each time I boot.